# Cannot make Scheduler move and moveStart event work

Tags: events, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I tried to make move and moveStart events work but with no luck.
Then I took demo html which demonstrated several events. I modified but still didn't work.
modified complete source code is attached below

please help me, since I am stuck on scheduler for 3 days.
I know that it is in beta but hoped to be worth working.

here is the code: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1V92zL4UpSvUW5ndGVwU2lWNjA/edit?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

Those events are not yet supported. They will be supported with the Q2 2013 SP1 release which is due later this month.

Comment: thank you for you fast response. Before the release comes out I have to find some way and as an alternative I will use save event to update or create operation.